# String replacement in filenames in linux

Tags: linux, bash, rename

I have a tonne of files called `File30_i.txt` for `i=1, 2, 3, 4, 5`...
Is there an easy way to quickly rename then `File20_i.txt` for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a tool for that called `rename`:

```
rename 's/File30/File20/' *.txt
```

For a preview run with `-n`:

```
rename -n 's/File30/File20/' *.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

My preferred way would be to use sed to generate a script for it, for example:

```
ls -1|sed 's/File30_\([^.]*\).txt/mv & File20_\1.txt/'|bash
```

This should rename as per the filenames you gave in the question. To preview the commands, you can do:

```
ls -1|sed 's/File30_\([^.]*\).txt/mv & File20_\1.txt/'
```

Answer (score 0):

[renamer](https://github.com/75lb/renamer) works on Windows, Mac and Linux:

```
$ renamer --find Find30 --replace Find20 *.txt
```